# What is type-safe in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

What is type-safe?

What does it mean and why is it important?

In my code error occured This function or variable may be unsafe. What does unsafe mean ?

```
#include <ctime> 

int compareValues() {

        time_t now = time(0);

        tm* ltm = localtime(&now); //Localtime: This function or variable may be unsafe 

        if ((_year == ltm->tm_year) && (_month == 1 + ltm->tm_mon) && (_day == ltm->tm_mday)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

If i put in `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to my code error is disabled but what does unsafe mean and what does `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` do ?

Comment: You enable `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` if you don't want confused Microsoft programmers to give you their subjective, incompetent opinions about your code.

Comment: `tm* ltm = localtime(&now);` is not valid C as `tm` as a _type_ is not defined.  Use `struct tm`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with type safety.

`localtime()` uses a static storage for its return value; this is not unsafe in general, but it might be a problem when using multithreading.

For this reason, Microsoft wants people to use `localtime_s()` instead, which uses a user-provided buffer.

However, if you really need to call this function from concurrent threads, I would recommend to use `localtime_r()` if you want to be portable (Posix-compliant at least), since `localtime_s()` isn't. The `*_r` function family generally denotes the *re-entrant* versions of the functions. Basically, re-entrancy is the feature, that a function can be called, while it is already invoked (running) elsewhere. Re-entrant code is always thread-safe, too.

Comment: Perhaps it is nice to add that the _r suffix denotes that the function is reentrant

Comment: ...or just don't call these functions from multiple threads. I really don't see why you would ever want to do that.

Comment: Perhaps also explaining what a re-entrant version is.